# Lazy Loading carga todo los modulos al iniciar en Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy implementando el lazyLoading en mi aplicación, pero revisando el depurador del navegador he notado que se cargan todos los modulos al principio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este comportamiento es normal? O estoy implmentando mal el lazyLoading?

Estas son las rutas de mi component-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'control-usuarios',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./control-usuarios/control-usuarios.module').then(
            (m) => m.ControlUsuariosModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'formulario',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./form/form.module').then((m) => m.FormModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'listado',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./pqr-listas/pqr-listas.module').then(
            (m) => m.PqrListasModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'revision',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./pqrs-revision/pqrs-revision.module').then(
            (m) => m.PqrsRevisionModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'perfil',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./user/user.module').then((m) => m.UserModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'reportes',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./reportes/reportes.module').then((m) => m.ReportesModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'galeria',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./gallery/gallery.module').then((m) => m.GalleryModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'infraestructuras',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./mapa-infraestructura/mapa-infraestructura.module').then(
            (m) => m.PqrMapaModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/perfil',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Y este es mi app-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
     // Routes
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: () => import('./auth/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule),
        },
      {
        path: 'olvido-contraseña',
        loadChildren: () => import('./auth/forgot-password/forgot-password.module').then(m => m.ForgotPasswordModule),
        },
      {
        path: 'reset-password/:token',
        loadChildren: () => import('./auth/reset-password/reset-password.module').then(m => m.ResetPasswordModule),
        },

      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./components/components.module').then(m => m.ComponentsModule),
        canLoad: [AutenticacionGuard],
      },
]
```

Comment: Puedes compartir tu AppRoutingModule completo?

Comment: que ruta es en la que estas?

Comment: En la de perfil, que es la me redirecciona el path ' ' del component-routing.ts

Comment: Obtienes el mismo comportamiento de ver todos los archivos en la pestaña "Red"? Recuerda que una cosa es que los archivos se encuentren ahí, y otra es que el navegador los vaya solicitando.

Comment: En el network parece que si carga los modulos ha medida que se carga. Pero no deberia cargarse en el source tambien a medida que se navega?

Comment: @Alezco05 no necesiariamente, para eso esta el cacheo de los datos